# Android : Error setting condition to background of listview

Tags: android, listview, background

I've try setting the background using condition when creating custom listview.

Here is the sample code of adapter view for listview :

```
    public lstViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
    {
       ......
       ......
       ......
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

    {

         View vi = convertView;
         if(position % 2 != 0)
         {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);

        }
         }
         else
         {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1,null);
        }
         }
         ....
         ....
         ....
     }
```

[image: Left : first lunch application , Right : after scroll up and down]

It display as normal but when i scroll up and down... it change randomly... 
any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: The way you do is not good on the performance.But if you still want to try you should inflate layout all times and don't reuse the convertview

Comment: @Henry yeah, i've just tested every scroll up and down... the value of postion is change all the time....i dunno why it's not fix ???

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will find something related here.

http://smartphonebysachin.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-listview-with-separator-and.html

There you can replace the image with a xml view for the background.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is good or not but i fix it by deleting the condition of covertView != null :

```
if(position % 2 != 0)
         {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);


         }
         else
         {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1,null);
      }
```